# CORBA Configuration in JBoss 7.1.1, Unable to get NameService

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, corba

I'm trying to setup a CORBA enabled application on JBoss 7.1.1 Final. It seems that I'm missing something because everything I try results in another exception. So, what I tried:

```
standalone -c standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=nodeA or
standalone -c standalone-full-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=nodeA
```

then the 2nd line here

```
GlobalData.orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, p);
orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
```

throws the exception:

```
(MSC service thread 1-9) IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0: org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0
    at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:1343) [jacorb-2.3.1.jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at MyApp.startServer(MyApp.java:145) [server.jar:]
```

My /conf folder contains a jacorb.properties with the entry

```
ORBInitRef.NameService=corbaloc::localhost:3828/JBoss/Naming/root
```

Can anyone bring some light into the dark?
Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for that problem, Jacorb require mandatory configuration (jacorb.propeity)
you can get that file from JBoss 4.2.2

Then

you need to include that file in your class path, to do that we create custom module

for instance go to jboss modules directory

create sub directory **custom/myconfig/main** for example

there add your property files

create module.xml file .. you will chose module name... for instnace custom.myconfig

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="custom.myconfig">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

    <dependencies>     
    </dependencies>
</module>

In your jboss-deployment-structure.xml include this module to your app


<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="custom.myconfig/>
        </dependencies>
        <resources>
        </resources>
    </deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="My_WAR.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="custom.myconfig" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
```

Hope that help as it work with me